# how can i modify hours when increasing minutes in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, timepicker

I am using p-calendar to select hours but hour does not modify after 59th minute and minute turns to 0. How can I solve this problem? I have to use p-calendar.

```
 <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="deliveryTime" timeOnly="true" [stepMinute]="minuteStep" [minDate]="deliveryDate"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: You can bind to the onSelect event that fires off a function that stores the new value (date object), compares it against the old value and have a condition that checks if it is going from 59 to 0, if so then you can also increase the hour by 1.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-yodjon?file=src/app/app.component.ts